# Creating a Cross-frequency table in R or MySQL

Tags: mysql, r

I have a table of user_id - category pairs. Users can fall into multiple categories. I'm am try to get counts cross-category for each possible outcome. i.e. number of users who were in category A and also category C, etc.

My raw data is structured like this:

[image: example results]

I would like results that look like this, showing counts cross-category:

[image: example results]

How can this be accomplished in R or MySQL? The data is quite large.

Here's are sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C"), class = "factor"), user_id = c(464L, 345L, 342L, 312L, 
345L, 234L, 423L, 464L, 756L, 756L, 345L, 345L, 464L, 345L, 234L, 
312L)), .Names = c("category", "user_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Any code snippets, thoughts on approach, functions, or package recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you! -John

Comment: Can you give an expected output for your sample data? I'm assuming it is not the second figure since that's not even symmetric.

Comment: Hi @josiber, you're right - that second figure is only an example of what results would look like. I can't figure out how to get any results yet until I can find a solution to this problem. The function would just be counts of users, though. Hope that helps.

Comment: since you've posted an example with 16 rows I would imagine you could calculate it by hand. Please do so and post the expected output, as you don't have a reproducible example until you do so.

Comment: Do you expect A-B to have value 1 or 3 in the output table? The only user with both categories is user 345, who has category labels A, B, B, B, C.

Comment: @SuperJohn: when you say "the data is quite large", how many records are you talking about? Are you planning to use this for collaborative filtering?

Comment: @AlexWoolford The table has ~ 1 million rows. I will not be using this for collaborative filtering but a report that shows the relative overlap of users and categories, i.e. 90% of users in category A are also in category C, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, I would approach this by first splitting up the data by user, computing all the unique pairs of categories for that user and then grouping together:

```
data$category <- as.character(data$category)
(combos <- do.call(rbind, tapply(data$category, data$user_id, function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  if (length(u) > 1) t(combn(u, 2))
  else NULL
})))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "C"  "A" 
# [2,] "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "B"  "C" 
# [4,] "B"  "A" 
# [5,] "C"  "A" 
# [6,] "A"  "C" 
# [7,] "C"  "B"
```

The last step is to tabulate the pairs, which can be done with the `table` function in R. We'll actually use `table` twice to capture (a, b) and (b, a) for each pairing of categories a and b:

```
table(combos[,1], combos[,2]) + table(combos[,2], combos[,1])
#     A B C
#   A 0 1 4
#   B 1 0 2
#   C 4 2 0
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply -  I tried this out on a sample data set and it worked great. I had to use a SQL solution, since I was stuck with 300M records. I didn't realize that the final data set would be that large! I don't know how to use data that big with R yet. In any case, thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample data provided I actually don't think the R solution provided by @josilber is correct, though I could be wrong given the lack of the example solution desired.  I think you could do this with `igraph` and its bipartite network representation of the data, but this could be inefficient on larger sets of data/categories.  As an alternative a relatively efficient calculation in R using a sparse matrix representation of the data can be done like this:

```
library('Matrix')
mat <- spMatrix(nrow=length(unique(data$category)),
    ncol=length(unique(data$user_id)),
    i = as.numeric(factor(data$category)),
    j = as.numeric(factor(data$user_id)),
    x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(data$category)))
)
rownames(mat) <- levels(factor(data$category))
colnames(mat) <- levels(factor(data$user_id))
mat

#mat_row <- mat %*% t(mat)

##  Based on @user20650's comment this is even more efficient than
##    the multiplication above:
mat_row <- tcrossprod(mat)
```

This I think yields the following correct output based on the sample data above:

```
> mat_row
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  A  B C
A 7  3 5
B 3 12 4
C 5  4 5
```

Comment: another alt ...  `tcrossprod(table(dat))`

Comment: Definitely! But if you have many users/categories (like in the millions) you could run into memory issues before the sparse matrix representation would.  But +1 for that approach on more manageable data sizes for sure!

Comment: also to be like josibers solution (except the diagonal) `tcrossprod(!!table(dat)) `

Comment: You are super right, that should be even more efficient I think.  I modified my solution to reflect this.

Comment: The differences in our solutions come down to how you deal with somebody who has multiple identical category labels. For instance, the only user with categories A and B is user id 345. They are labeled with A once and B three times, leading you to label A-B as 3 and me to label it as 1 (one person). Only OP can tell us which is preferred. I thought my interpretation was correct because of the language from the question: "number of users who were in category A and also category C" -- note that user id 345 is just one user, not three.

Comment: Yeah, I agree! I just assumed that was information the OP wanted captured but it's hard to say from the original question wording.  Coming at it from a typical bipartite network analysis perspective I would have gotten to your solution, but it didn't make sense to me given the sample data which has the duplicate 345 -> B associations to not count them.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can readily do this in a three-column format:

```
select a.category, b.category, count(*)
from pairs a join
     pairs b
     on a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.category, b.category;
```

Producing a table as a matrix is challenging in SQL, unless you know all the column names.  Otherwise, you need a dynamic pivot (google:  "mysql dynamic pivot").  For most purposes in the *database*, the three column format is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr` to create a list of all the unique pairs, and the `crossprod` to count the number of users that are common to a pair of categories.

```
> library(dplyr)
> data <- data %>% group_by(user_id, category) %>% summarize(records = sign(n()))
> crossprod(table(data$user_id, data$category))

    A B C
  A 4 1 4
  B 1 4 2
  C 4 2 5
```